# MySQLdb and Python 3.X

Tags: python, mysql

I need the library for work in python 3.1.3 with MySQL, but I can't found it... I have searched for the way of installation but I can´t...

Trying to port the module I obtain this error:

```
Windows Error [error2] System can´t found the file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find MySQL-python at [Golhke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository for 3.1-3.2

Comment: gracias Joaquin! but for windows what can I do?? saludoss

Comment: Well,  your post indicated "Windows Error"... Can not help with Ubuntu, sorry

Comment: yes, because I´m doing test in Windows but I need the same for Ubuntu! In windows I already have soluted with your help! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [MySQL Connector/Python](https://launchpad.net/myconnpy) on Windows and Python v3.1
It's pure Python, no MySQL software or compiling required.